# Apache POI sets Values in Cells of an xlsx file, but doesnt confirm them in the processing strip

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to write values into a xlsx file using java and POI.
It's nearly working as I want, but i have the following Problem:
The Values that my programm writes into the xlsx file are displayed there, but excel doesn't use my VLOOKUP and displays #N/A untill I go into the 
processing strip and press Enter, then it works..

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class XLSXEditor {

    public XLSXEditor(){

    }

    public void xlsxWriter(String path, String uName, Date date/*, String timeF, String timeT*/) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File excel = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(1);
        int r = getNonBlankRowCount(path);
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);

        //Datum Style
        CellStyle csDate = book.createCellStyle();
        CreationHelper createHelper = book.getCreationHelper();
        csDate.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"));
        csDate.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_TURQUOISE.getIndex());
        csDate.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        //uname style
        CellStyle csUname = book.createCellStyle();
        csUname.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_TURQUOISE.getIndex());
        csUname.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);


        //fill username column in xlsx file
        XSSFCell celluName = row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
        while(celluName != null){
            r++;
            row = sheet.createRow(r);
            celluName = row.createCell(0);
        }
        if(celluName == null){

            celluName = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(0);
            celluName.setCellStyle(csUname);
        }
        celluName.setCellValue(uName);

        //fill date column in xlsx file
        XSSFCell cellDate = row.getCell(5, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
        while(cellDate != null){
            r++;
            row = sheet.createRow(r);
            cellDate = row.getCell(5);
        }
        if(cellDate == null){
            cellDate = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(5);
            cellDate.setCellValue(date);
            cellDate.setCellStyle(csDate);
        }

        //fill PNr column in xlsx file
        int r1 = r+1;
        XSSFCell cellPNr = row.getCell(1, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
        cellPNr = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(1);
        cellPNr.setCellValue("=SVERWEIS(A"+r1+";'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98;2;FALSCH)");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        book.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    public int getNonBlankRowCount(String path) throws IOException{
        File excel = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(1);
        int rowCount = 0;
        int index = book.getSheetIndex(sheet);
        if(index==-1){
            rowCount=-1;
            return rowCount;
        }
        else{
            sheet=book.getSheetAt(index);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
            rowCount=0;
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
                Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
                XSSFCell cell =(XSSFCell) row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                if(cell == null){
                    break;
                }
                rowCount++;
            }
            return rowCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula cell content is fundamentally different from text cell content in `Excel`. Your code line:

```
cellPNr.setCellValue("=SVERWEIS(A"+r1+";'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98;2;FALSCH)");
```

sets a string cell value instead of a formula. Do using [Cell.setCellFormula](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellFormula-java.lang.String-) instead to set formula cell content.

And since `Excel` stores only formulas in English_US notation in its files you need using English_US notation of the formula:

```
cellPNr.setCellFormula("VLOOKUP(A"+r1+",'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98,2,FALSE)");
```

English_US notation means English function names (for ex. `VLOOKUP` instead of `SVERWEIS`), English constant names (for ex. `FALSE` instead of `FALSCH`), comma as parameter delimiter (for ex. `VLOOKUP(A1,F1:G100,2,FALSE)` instead of `VLOOKUP(A1;F1:G100;2;FALSE)`) and dot as decimal delimiter in floating point literals (for ex. `SUM(1.23, 3.45, 4)` instead of `SUMME(1,23; 3,45; 4)`.

The localization is made in the localized `Excel` GUI versions **after** opening the file.

And then you need some kind of [Formula Recalculation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Recalculation+of+Formulas). Simplest way is by delegating re-calculation to Excel by setting:

```
book.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```

before writing out the `book`.

Comment: Thank you, I think thats the right soultion, but now i have another problem:
in the line: cellPNr.setCellFormula("VLOOKUP(A"+r1+",'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98,2,FALSE)"); I get an FormulaParseException telling me there is an parse error near char 10. so this error occurs when i try to parse my String r1

Comment: Please show the exact error. Also try to debug. For example by concatenating the formula string before using it: `String formula = "VLOOKUP(A"+r1+",'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98,2,FALSE)"; System.out.println(formula); cellPNr.setCellFormula(formula);`. What does `formula` contains?

Comment: My formula String is: "VLOOKUP(A4;'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98;2;FALSCH)". I already tryed concantenating the Formula String before using it. This is the thrown Exception: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Parse error near char 10 ';' in specified formula 'VLOOKUP(A4;'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98;2;FALSCH)'. Expected ',' or ')'"

Comment: As said, all in English_US notation. So comma instead of semi-colon and  FALSE instead of FALSCH. `String formula = "VLOOKUP(A"+r1+",'MA Stamm'!$A$2:$E$98,2,FALSE)"`

Comment: Oh, sry for asking twice :/ Thank you, now it works as i want :)

Comment: Hey, I got one more question. Do you know, which xml file in my xlsx is edited, if book.setForceFormulaRecalculation is executed?

Comment: [public void setForceFormulaRecalculation(boolean value)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.java?view=markup#l2211). So `/xl/workbook.xml` is changed to `...<calcPr calcMode="auto" calcId="0"/>...`.

Comment: Do u know if it is possible to recalculate the file, that sormulas are calculated, but avoid the save changes messagebox thats caused by this method? Atm I'm trying to change /xl/workbook.xml after executing the recalc..Butafter editing the Formulas just print 0 and aren#t calculated

Comment: @Robin: Please do not using comments for asking new questions. That is not what comments are for. Ask a new question if you have one and do describing the problem properly there. To a question as asked in your last comment I would not have an answer because the probem is not clear.

Comment: I aksed a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494698/how-to-calculate-formulas-in-excel-with-apache-poi-and-avoid-the-save-changes)