# How to calculate Formulas in Excel with Apache-POI and avoid the "save changes" messagebox?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I've got the following Problem: I wrote a Java programm that writes values into a xlsx file. This xlsx file calculates new values using Formulas. Now I want to get this calculated Values out of the xlsx file. The Problem is, that I don't get the calculated values into my Java programm, because changes aren't saved.
So I tryed to edit the xl/workbook.xml in the xlsx file to get rid of that save changes question. That works, but now the formula cells that I try to read return a default value and not the calculated value. So atm I have 2 options: I use

```
workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)
```

to calculate Values that i can't read without manually saving the file. Or I edit the xl/workbook.xml to avoid manually saving the file, but then the formulas don't calculate values.. in both cases my programm can just read default values and not the calculated ones that I want..
Here is my code to edit the xml:

```
 public void editXML(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path);
    final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\Excels\\SO_Berechnung_nosave.xlsx"));
    for(Enumeration e = zipFile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();){
        ZipEntry entryIn = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
//    if(!(entryIn.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("xl/workbook.xml"))){
            System.out.println(entryIn.getName());
            zos.putNextEntry(entryIn);
            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entryIn);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while((len = (is.read(buffer)))>0){
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

//        } 
        zos.flush();
        zos.closeEntry();
    } 

    File excel = new File("D:\\Excels\\SO_Berechnung_nosave.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Excels\\SO_Berechnung_nosave.xlsx");
    book.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
    book.write(fos);
    fis.close();
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    for(Enumeration e = zipFile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();){
        System.out.println("????????????????????????");
        ZipEntry entryIn = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
        if(entryIn.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("xl/workbook.xml")){
            System.out.println("RIGHT ENTRY FOUND AND WORKBOOK:XML WILL BE CHANGED NOW");
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("xl\\workbook.xml"));
            System.out.println("RIGHT ENTRY FOUND AND WORKBOOK:XML WILL BE CHANGED NOW");
            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entryIn);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int len;
            while(is.read(buffer) >= 0){
                String s = new String(buffer);
                //Add standallone yes
                String sFirstLine = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
                String rFirstLine = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
                if(s.contains(sFirstLine)){
                    s = s.replace(sFirstLine, rFirstLine);
                    System.out.println("firstLine old: " + sFirstLine);
                    System.out.println("firstLine new: " + rFirstLine);
                }

                //replace wrong path
                String sPath = "\\Empty";
                String rPath = "";
                if(s.contains(sPath)){
                    s = s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(sPath), Matcher.quoteReplacement(rPath));
                    System.out.println("path old: " + sPath);
                    System.out.println("path new: " + rPath);
                }

                //replace FileVersion
                String searchFileVersion = "/main\"><fileVersion appName=\"xl\" lastEdited=\"6\" lowestEdited=\"6\" rupBuild=\"14420\"/>"; //I know its 2times the same
                String replaceFileVersion =  "/main\"><fileVersion appName=\"xl\" lastEdited=\"6\" lowestEdited=\"6\" rupBuild=\"14420\"/>";//the rup Build should be right
                if(s.contains(searchFileVersion)){
                    s = s.replaceAll(searchFileVersion, replaceFileVersion);
                    System.out.println("fileVersion old: " + searchFileVersion);
                    System.out.println("fileVersion new: " + replaceFileVersion);
                }

                //replace calcId
                String searchCalcId = "<calcPr calcId=\"0\"/>";
                String replaceCalcId = "<calcPr calcId=\"152511\"/>"; //2147483647   152511
                if(s.contains(searchCalcId)){
                    s = s.replaceAll(searchCalcId, replaceCalcId);
                    System.out.println("calcId old: " + searchCalcId);
                    System.out.println("calcId new: " + replaceCalcId);
                }

                //replace Alternate
                String searchAlternateContent = "<mc:AlternateContent>";
                String replaceAlternateContent = "<mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\">";
                if(s.contains(searchAlternateContent)){
                    s = s.replaceAll(searchAlternateContent, replaceAlternateContent);
                    System.out.println("AlternateContent old: " + searchAlternateContent);
                    System.out.println("AlternateContent new: " + replaceAlternateContent);
                }
                //idk if this has impact...
                String searchXmlns = "mc:Ignorable=\"x15\" "
                        + "xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\" "
                        + "xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\" "
                        + "xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" "
                        + "xmlns:x15=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main\">";
                String replaceXmlns = "xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\" "
                        + "xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\" "
                        + "xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" "
                        + "mc:Ignorable=\"x15\" "
                        + "xmlns:x15=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main\">";
                if(s.contains(searchXmlns)){
                    s = s.replaceAll(searchXmlns, replaceXmlns);
                    System.out.println("AlternateContent old: " + searchXmlns);
                    System.out.println("AlternateContent new: " + replaceXmlns);
                }

                //replace last line
                String sWb = "</workbook";
                String rWb = "</workbook>";
                if(s.contains(sWb)){
                    s = s.replaceAll(sWb, rWb);
                    System.out.println("Workbook old: " + sWb);
                    System.out.println("Workbook new: " + rWb);
                }

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(s);
                System.out.println("");

                len = s.trim().length();
                buffer = s.getBytes();
                zos.write(buffer, 0, (len < buffer.length) ? len : buffer.length);
            }
        }
    }

    zos.flush();
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();


}
```

I allready tryed to copy all xml files except the xl/workbook.xml to a new created xlsx and then import the edited xl/workbook.xml but then the formulas didn't work.. And sry for that spaghetti-code, but i tryed i lot of things and didn't wanted do delete things that could lead me to a working solution. Explanation of all the replacements I do: I compared the xl/workbook.xml before saving and after saving and eliminated all differences. If I compare the xml's now there are no more differences.

### Update:

According to the accepted answer, I don't use the code above anymore. And i added 
`book.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();` to my code in the following context:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
 book.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
 //XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells((XSSFWorkbook) book);
 book.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
 book.write(fos);
 fis.close();
 fos.flush();
 fos.close();
```

And now i get the followign Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid ValueEval type passed for conversion: (class org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.collectValue(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:219)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.collectValues(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:179)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.getNumberArray(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:128)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.evaluate(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:90)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:540)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:303)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:245)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:268)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:155)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:335)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:326)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:256)
at XLSXEditor.searchWriter(XLSXEditor.java:218)
at Main.fillTable(Main.java:962)
at Main.btShowActionPerformed(Main.java:715)
at Main.access$900(Main.java:25)
at Main$11.actionPerformed(Main.java:402)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I checked all functions I use in my fomulas [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#appendixA) and they are all offered.. Could there be a problem, caused by the localization or something?

Comment: Ehm: `HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:326)  <- XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:256)`: The `apache poi` version where `XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll` had called `HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells` on code line 256 was version `3.11`. What about updating to a more current version? Latest stable release is `3.17`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "I wrote a Java programm that writes values into a xlsx file. This
>   xlsx file calculates new values using Formulas. Now I want to get this
>   calculated Values out of the xlsx file. The Problem is, that I don't
>   get the calculated values into my Java programm, because changes
>   aren't saved. "

Until now your assumptions are correct.

> "So I tryed to edit the xl/workbook.xml in the xlsx file to get rid of
>   that save changes question. "

But now you are on the wrong way.

The `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)` delegates the recalculation of formulas to `Excel`'s GUI. The recalculation is done if `Excel`'s GUI is opening the file next time. When recalculated, changes **were** made. So the question about save the changes is legit. And only **after** saving the changes, which are the recalculated formula results, those results will be stored in the file. And then the results will only be readable using `apache poi` after new creating a `Workbook` from that file.

But delegating the recalculation is only **one** option for [recalculating formulas](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation). The other option is using a [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html) and it's [evaluateAll](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAll--) method for example.

```
...
workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
...
```

After that all formulas will be evaluated using `apache poi` and the new results will be rereadable.

Of course that only works for formulas which are supported by `apache poi`' s `FormulaEvaluator`. There are some which are not supported. Then you cannot simply do `evaluateAll` but must only evaluate the cells which contains supported formulas.

In that context the whole chapter about [Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html) may be of interest.

**Update:**

As said already not all formulas are supported until now. And `apache poi` is not as tolerant as `Excel` will be.

According to the error in the **Update** part of the question, there is a [MissingArgEval](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/MissingArgEval.html) aka "a missed argument" used in a formula which normally should not have such missed arguments.

For example `Excel` tolerates simply giving nothing as a parameter in a formula where `0` is meant. For ex.  `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Text",Z:Z,))` instead of `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Text",Z:Z,0))`. But the `apache poi` `FormulaEvaluator` will not tolerate this.

So you now needs investigating which formula causes the error. So instead `evaluateAll` do looping over the cells to evaluate as described in [Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html) - "Re-calculating all formulas in a Workbook":

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = book.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
for (Sheet sheet : book) {
    for (Row r : sheet) {
        for (Cell c : r) {
            if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
System.out.println(c.getAddress() + ":" + c.getCellFormula());
                evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There the debug `System.out.println` should tell you which cell causes the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at the Update of my question

Comment: Thank you! It seems like that's the problem. I'll continue debugging and change my formulas and add a comment if it works :)

Comment: @Robin: Glad it works now. But nevertheless you should update from your `apache poi 3.11` and always using the latest stable release. The `apache poi` project is highly in development and you are renouncing on many improvements if you remain on old versions. Hopefully sometime in later versions `apache poi` will behave exact as Excel does. And then you should be able participating on this improvement.

Comment: I will upgrade as soon, as I finished my project and saved it. Just in case that it doesn't work with newer versions.. For following projects I will use the latest version when I start programming :)